# Hadoop command to run bash script in hadoop cluster

Tags: shell, hadoop, cloudera, oozie-workflow

I've a shell script (count.sh) which counts the number of lines in a file.
This script has been copied into hdfs and am currently using Oozie workflow to execute this script.

However, I was wondering if there is a way to execute this shell script from command line.

Ex:

In unix: `[myuser@myserver ~]$./count.sh`

Equivalent of this when count.sh is in hadoop cluster location *'/user/cloudera/myscripts/count.sh'*.

I read this [Hadoop command to run bash script in hadoop cluster](https://gist.github.com/mehikmat/9229574), but am still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called `Hadoop streaming`.

You can look at the official documentation [Hadoop Streaming](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html) to find out more or look at [Writing An Hadoop MapReduce Program In Python](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/) (instead of python, put in your bash script) to understand how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but I just came across it myself and figured I could add a bit of info to it for the future.

Like Camille said, but this also works with parameters, for instance if you are using bash.

```
hdfs dfs -cat /path/file | exec bash -s param1 param2 param3 param4
```

By gathering the file with `cat`, you can start the script as a bash file with `execute`.
`-s` enables parameters.

Answer (score 0):

hadoop fs -cat /path/count.sh|exec sh

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: This runs locally, not in YARN